# data table search data correctly but when i remove search text from search box data didn't come again in tables

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

```
  <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Vendor Code</th>
                                <th>Vendor Name</th>
                                <th>Vendor Type</th>
                                <th>Credit Days</th>
                                <th  width="4px">Edit</th>
                                <th  width="4px">Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="VendorList"></tbody>

                    </table>
```

> here is my ajax call search box work properly but when i remove text from search box it table didnot fill again with data
>   i dont know what happen in it 
>   need help !

```
    $.get("/Vendor/GetVendorList", null, DataBind);
    function DataBind(VendorList) {
        var setdata = $("#VendorList");
        for (var i = 0; i < VendorList.length; i++) {
            var Data = "<tr 'class='row" + VendorList[i].VendorID + "'>" +
                 "<td>" + VendorList[i].VendorCode + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + VendorList[i].VendorName + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + VendorList[i].VendorType + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + VendorList[i].CreditDays + "</td>" +
                 " <td>" + "<a href='/vendor/Addvendor/?VendorID=" + VendorList[i].VendorID + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>" + " </td>" +
                 " <td>" + "<a href='/vendor/deleterecord/?DeleteId=" + VendorList[i].VendorID + "' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" + " </td>" +
            "</tr>";
            setdata.append(Data);
            $("#example1").DataTable();
        }
    }

</script>
```

here is my controller

```
 public JsonResult GetVendorList()
    {
        List<VendorViewModel> ven = ObjModel.Vendors.Select(x => new VendorViewModel
        {
            VendorID = x.VendorID,
            VendorName = x.VendorName,
            VendorType = x.VendorType,
            VendorCode = x.VendorCode,
            VendorEmail = x.VendorEmail,
            VendorPhoneNo = x.VendorPhoneNo,
            VendorMobileNo = x.VendorMobileNo,
            VendorAddress = x.VendorAddress,
            CreditDays = x.CreditDays,
            IsActive = x.IsActive,
            Website = x.Website,
            IsDelete = x.IsDelete,
            UserID = x.UserID,
            ComapnyId = x.ComapnyId
        }).ToList();
        return Json(ven, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is my JSON method where data comes from

Comment: How do you filter data in controller?

Comment: also, if you remove text, are you getting all data or not?

Comment: iam not filtering data in controller , ajax call get data and return into JSON

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers yes when i type in searchbox it is filtering perfectly but when i remove text from search box it is not getting back data into table

Comment: show your controller code as well

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers see above  i also show my controller

Comment: try to clear table first and after append HTML. also every time you don't need to do $("#example1").DataTable();

Comment: where and how can i clear table ?? and where i call **$("#example1").DataTable();** many times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First clear all rows of table. you are appending every time.

```
$('#example1 tbody').empty();
```

Also, you don't need to specify every time to table as DataTable in loop.

```
$.get("/Vendor/GetVendorList", null, DataBind);
    function DataBind(VendorList) {
        $('#example1 tbody').empty();
        var setdata = $("#VendorList");
        for (var i = 0; i < VendorList.length; i++) {
            var Data = "<tr 'class='row" + VendorList[i].VendorID + "'>" +
                 "<td>" + VendorList[i].VendorCode + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + VendorList[i].VendorName + "</td>" +
                 "<td>" + VendorList[i].VendorType + "</td>" +
                  "<td>" + VendorList[i].CreditDays + "</td>" +
                 " <td>" + "<a href='/vendor/Addvendor/?VendorID=" + VendorList[i].VendorID + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>" + " </td>" +
                 " <td>" + "<a href='/vendor/deleterecord/?DeleteId=" + VendorList[i].VendorID + "' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" + " </td>" +
            "</tr>";
            setdata.append(Data);
        }
        $("#example1").DataTable();
    }
```

Comment: I've updated some code. I misunderstood between VendorList and example1